# Graph problem: Find whether two nodes share the same branch in O(1) time and O(1) storage per node

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree, traversal

Say we have a directed tree (directed graph). So, over time, we build over the main branch, where we define the main branch as the longest branch from the root (first node in the whole tree), and while we're building it, we may build new branches at any time by attaching new nodes to arbitrary nodes, but most of the time, we build upon the tip (upon the longest branch).

The graph node has the form:

```
struct {
    int id;
    int prev_node_id; // this is what links nodes together
}
```

**Say that we select two random nodes X and Y. The question is: Do those nodes share a branch?**

Every node is defined by an ID (cryptographic hash basically, simplified by an int here). One solution to this problem is that we simply go back in the graph starting from one node, until we meet the other node. This requires looping over all the nodes in a branch, so this is O(N) where N is the number of nodes in a branch, which can be very, very long (millions of nodes). Is there any kind of data that we can build into the nodes that can make this operation O(1), where this data also is O(1) in size per node?

**My solution number one (bad because it's O(N) in storage per node):**

We add a arbitrary long prime number to the datastructure:

```
struct {
    int id;
    int prev_node_id;
    ArbitraryPrecisionInt branch_index;
}
```

Whenever we attach a node to any part of the tree, we define the `branch_index` to be:

```
branch_index_new = branch_index_old * new_prime_number;
```

where the new prime number comes from a singleton generator. Assuming we have a couple of million nodes, this is not that expensive. At least it's not that bad.

So, do nodes X and Y share the same branch?

The answer is YES if: `X % Y == 0` or `Y % X == 0`.

The problem here, the size of this product will grow very fast. The product of the first 1000 prime numbers is huge.

**My solution number two (kind of bad because it's O(log(N)) in search time but O(1) storage per node):**

```
struct {
    int id;
    int prev_node_id;
    int branch_id;
}
```

`branch_id` basically comes from a singleton. We start from 0, and for every new node we create, we have two cases.

1. If the node we added is on the tip of the tree (no other branches exist at that node), we add the same value
2. If a branch exists already at that node, we increment the number by one (the numbers are generated from a singleton, so there will never be duplicates).

After that, we create a database table where we write the height of every new increment vs every value (we define the height as the length from the root node up to that node).

So, do nodes X and Y share the same branch? To answer that, we look at X's `branch_id`, then we look in the database, and we find the height at which the branch was created. We go there, and find the `branch_id` of the point before. We keep doing this until we either reach the root (fail) or find the `branch_id` of Y.

---

This whole story is a blockchain problem I'm trying to solve. The details of the real problem are really complicated and unnecessary to go through. However, feel free to chat with me if you're interested. I'm saying this because someone will definitely call this an XY problem.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: This seems closely related to LCA queries, which can be done in O(1). My main concern is that if you're dealing with a blockchain the tree is probably mutable? And you need to answer these queries while updating the tree?

Comment: @Primusa I never heard of LCA queries before, I'll be looking into that now. Thanks for that. About the mutability, I think you meant "immutable", not mutable, which is true and is a legitimate concern. But I still can modify fields that don't contribute to the hash of the node. Not all fields in a node are used to calculate a the hash. I hope I caught what you meant.

Comment: By mutable I mean mutable - most data structures of this type require an `O(N)` or `O(NlogN)` preprocessing step and then are able to answer queries very quickly. The problem is that after you preprocess you can't add new nodes to the structure.

Comment: @Primusa Yeah, if that's the case, then no. That won't work. I need to consistently keep adding new nodes (blocks) to the tree. I don't understand the problem given because I don't know LCA queries yet.

Comment: Additionally I have doubts about solution #2 - Can't you have duplicate branch ids (let's say I add nodes to different nodes on the main branch)

Comment: @Primusa There's a singleton that generates the numbers. I'll make that clear in the text.

Comment: hmm even then I think it's possible to create an adversarial tree that has `O(N)` search time. Say I send in new nodes in the form `[A, B]` where `B` is a new node attached to `A`. Let the root be `A`. `[A, B], [B, C], [B, D], [D, E], [D, F], [F, G]...`, any node doing a branch search has to travel up the chain `F -> D -> B -> A` which is every other node

Comment: @Primusa You're right. But blockchains won't have that, because most branches will be built on the tip. That's basically where the mining competition lies. While this whole problem is being solved to solve a spam attack, I'm also studying whether an attack can be carried with this situation as well, and how hard it'll be, given that the attacker won't necessarily know the internal structure of the tree of a node.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear up the terminology:  As you add leaves to the tree, you want to be able to pick any two nodes and determine if one is an ancestor of the other.

Yes, you can do this.  The basic procedure is:

- Every node has two labels -- a start label and an end label.  These are like numbers in that there is a total ordering among labels
- When you add a new child to a node, you give it start and end labels that are between the parent's end label, and the end label of its last child, or the parent's start and end label if you're adding a the first child.
- Every node's start and end labels will then define a range corresponding to its subtree, so that you can test just by comparing labels to see if one node is in the subtree of the other.

Of course, you can't just use numbers for these labels, because you'll eventually run out of bits if you keep adding children into the smallest available interval.

You could use strings, because it's always possible to generate a string between two others, but then the storage is unbounded and comparison can take more than O(1) time.

So, you need some kind of magic label type that lets you add as many as you want between any pair of labels, and still lets you compare them quickly.

The problem is called the order maintenance problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-maintenance_problem

The most practical way in most cases, I think, is the simple algorithm in this paper: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/maintaining-order.pdf .  That paper also mentions order maintenance as a solution to exactly your problem.

With that algorithm, you can use numbers in a linked list, as long as the number type can hold N<sup>2</sup>, and adding new entries takes amortized O(log N) time.

Increasingly complex structures can give you better theoretical results, all the way down to non-amoritzed O(1) time insertion and O(1) time compares, but that gets very complicated.

Comment: Thank you! This kind of "number" or basically math function, is exactly what I've been looking for, and this is what lead me to the prime numbers solution, which is not the best. If I understand what you said, then Finding the structure is the challenge, and it seems not to be an easy one. I also hope that linked list is bound in size, otherwise we're back to square one. I'll look into these references and come back to you soon.

Comment: From reading the article, if I understand it correctly, the tree has to be rearrangeable, which will eventually lead to the amortized time of O(log N). That's unfortunately not applicable to blockchains.

Comment: You don't need to rearrange the tree.  You use an extra doubly-linked list for the labels.  The tree nodes have a pointer to their label nodes, and the on-line list labelling algorithm modifies the labels in those nodes.